# In VS Code, how can I revert selecting 'weaker method for storing passwords'

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had some issues with keyring, and accidentally has pressed 'use weaker method for storing passwords' on VS Code.
How do I cancel it and go back to using keyring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a message string in the VS Code codebase like the one you showed, but there's only one other security/password-related message that uses the word "weaker", in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/860d67064a9c1ef8ce0c8de35a78bea01033f76c/src/vs/workbench/services/secrets/electron-sandbox/secretStorageService.ts#L74. A button with the text "Use weaker encryption", and a detail string:

> Open the troubleshooting guide to address this or you can use weaker encryption that doesn't use the OS keyring.

Based on the button's `this._jsonEditingService.write(this._environmentService.argvResource, [{ path: ['password-store'], value: PasswordStoreCLIOption.basic }], true);`, I'd say check your argv.json file (you can open it from VS Code using the `Preferences: Configure Runtime Arguments` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)), and if there's a line like `"password-store": "basic"`, delete it (in which case you'll probably get the prompt again), or set it directly to [whichever option](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/860d67064a9c1ef8ce0c8de35a78bea01033f76c/src/vs/platform/encryption/common/encryptionService.ts#L31) you want.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you! This is what I was looking for! Great idea to look up into the code, I will note it for the feature.